# Calling method in method gets different result when using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have two methods there, `binToDec` that converts user input in Binary to Decimal and `decToHex` that converts Decimal to Hexadecimal.

```
public static int binToDec(int num){

  int result = 0;
  int exp = 0;
  while(num != 0){
     int x = num %10;
     result += x *Math.pow(2,exp);
     exp++;
     num = num / 10;
  }
  return result;          
} 


public static String decToHex(int num){
  String result = "";
  int n = num;
  int remainder = n % 16;

  if (n == 0) {
     return "";
  } else {
     switch (remainder) {
        case 10:
           result = "A";
           break;
        case 11:
           result = "B";
           break;
        case 12:
           result = "C";
           break;
        case 13:
           result = "D";
           break;
        case 14:
           result = "E";
           break;
        case 15:
           result = "F";
           break;
        default:
           result = remainder + result;
           break;
     }
     String finalResult = decToHex(n/ 16 ) + result;
     return finalResult;

  }
}
```

The problem is when I make a new method called `binToHex` that converts Binary to Hexadecimal, the results are different when I compare it to an online converter. I only called the methods from above. Here's my `binToHex`.

```
public static String binToHex(int num) {
  int binToDec = binToDec(num);
  String result = decToHex(num);
  return result;
  }
```

For example: When I enter **1011** in `binToHex`, I get my result as **3F3** BUT, when I manually go through both methods by first entering **1011** on `binToDec` and then use the result from `binToDec` on `decToHex`, I get **B** which is the correct answer. Why is it different when I put them in a method?

Comment: You’re not using the `binToDec` variable.

Comment: I’d expect `binToDec()` and `decToHex()` to take string inputs. `int`s don’t have a base.

Comment: How come I did not see such small error.... Thank you @Biffen. How can I close this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling num in `decToHex` instead of `binToDec` which is why your output is wrong. Just a typo.

Comment: ty yes i got it

Answer (score 0):

In fact it's only a small error. Instead of `String result = decToHex(num);`, you should have `String result = decToHex(binToDec);`. As you can see, you're asking the hexadecimal of 1011 (decimal) which is 3F3.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, `decToHex(num)` should be `decToHex(binToDec)`, so you use the result of the first function in the second.

```
public static String binToHex(int num) {
  int binToDec = binToDec(num);
  String result = decToHex(binToDec); // Typo was here
  return result;
}
```